# MYSQL: Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL on Windows OS, and am getting an error upon attempting to create a foreign key between two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tf_traffic_stats  ( 
domain_name     char(100) NOT NULL,
session_count   int(11) NULL,
search_count    int(11) NULL,
click_count     int(11) NULL,
revenue         float NULL,
rpm             float NULL,
cpc             float NULL,
traffic_date    date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
PRIMARY KEY(domain_name,traffic_date))
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE td_domain_name  ( 
domain_id   int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
domain_name char(100) NOT NULL,
update_date date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(domain_id))
```

The following statement gives me the error present in the subject line (cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails):

```
ALTER TABLE td_domain_name
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_domain_name
FOREIGN KEY(domain_name)
REFERENCES tf_traffic_stats(domain_name)
ON DELETE RESTRICT 
     ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of what may be causing the error. I also have a foreign key referencing td_domain_name.domain_id, but I don't *think* this should be interfering...

Also, as a workaround (*failed*) to this issue (which I'm sure can be easily resolved), I've tried simply performing a

```
td_domain_name left outer join tf_traffic_stats on td_domain_name.domain_name=tf_traffic_stats.domain_name
```

; however, the number of records do not match up as they should (i.e., left outer join not successful).

Appreciate it!

Comment: Is there any data in these tables?

Comment: Yes, there is plenty of data in the tables. td_domain_name contains a static list, while tf_traffic_stats has much more, and will be updated more frequently

Answer (score 3):

You have `td_domain_name.domain_name` values that don't have matching `tf_traffic_stats.domain_name` values. You must fix this before adding the foreign key constraint.

You can find the problematic rows using the following query:

```
SELECT td_domain_name.domain_name
FROM td_domain_name LEFT JOIN tf_traffic_stats
  ON td_domain_name.domain_name = tf_traffic_stats.domain_name
WHERE tf_traffic_stats.domain_name IS NULL
```

Comment: This is all very helpful! I do in fact have records that don't match..However, is there a way to conserve those values in td_domain_name - hence being the point of a left outer join?

Comment: @DalivDali - The purpose of the foreign key constraint is to limit valid values to those that match what's in the other table. If you want to have values that don't match, don't add the constraint. After you add the constraint, left joins will still be useful for finding domain names in `tf_traffic_stats` that don't have any matches in `td_domain_name`.

Comment: Another conundrum - I try to delete those orphaned records and once again receive the same error message - the records in     td_domain_name are referenced by another table (there is another foreign key). I don't want to be running in circles this way, so perhaps there is a better way to set up my tables?

Answer (score 1):

There's [a lot of reasons](http://www.verysimple.com/blog/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) that foreign keys can produce that error.  Unfortunately, MySQL isn't very specific about which reason it is.

It looks like you've got the proper indexes, and your column types match, so my guess is that you have some data in the second table that can't be correlated to the first one.  Something like the following query will show you any rows from `td_domain_name` that don't have a corresponding domain name in `tf_traffic_stats`:

```
SELECT * FROM td_domain_name WHERE domain_name NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(domain_name) FROM tf_traffic_stats);
```

Before you can create the foreign key restraint, you'll have to get rid of the entries in `td_domain_name` that can't be matched to `tf_traffic_stats`, or else create corresponding entries in `tf_traffic_stats`.

Just as an aside, it sounds like from your comments that td_domain_name is a static list of domains.  I'm going to make a wild guess based on your table names that you might want the foreign key the other way around, ie. ensuring that every domain in `tf_traffic_stats` exists in `td_domain_name`?

Comment: Zombat, you are right. I have attempted creating a foreign key the other way as well, and have encountered another curious error: Can't create table 'fl_domain_group_randomizer.#sql-4c4_10' (errno: 150)

Comment: Hmm... not sure about that particular error, but you will need an index on `td_domain_name.domain_name` if you're going the other way now.  Make sure to do a `ALTER TABLE td_domain_name ADD INDEX(domain_name);` before trying the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more details as to exactly why the query is failing with `SHOW INNODB STATUS`. Buried in the output is a section called `LAST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`, which will explain in greater detail why the key's failing.

If both of those tables have data in them, then most likely there's one more or more values in the td_domain_name table that aren't present in the tf_traffic_stats table, causing the FK creation to fail. If you absolutely have to have the FK created without fixing the mis-matched keys, you can temporarily disable the FK checks with `set foreign_key_checks=0`, then do the `alter` statement.